# How can I create a firebase project without an organization

Tags: firebase

How can I create a firebase project without selecting parent resource. When I try to create a project with an new account, I don't need to use resources from an parent organization if I use a new account. Here is a picture of the screen i get https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWtPY.png